# La négation de la phrase "Mon travail est intéressant"

Tags: grammaire, négation

Est-ce que la négation de la phrase "Mon travail est intéressant" est: "Mon travail est n'intéressant pas"? Ou "Mon travail n'est pas intéressant"? Et pourquoi?

Merci.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Mon travail est intéressant.
>   Mon travail n'est pas intéressant.

Pourquoi ? C'est une règle de grammaire<sup>1</sup> : **le verbe conjugué se place entre *ne* et *pas***.

> Je ne suis pas d'accord.
>   Je ne vais pas à cette soirée.

**Un verbe à l'infinitif se place après *pas*.**

> Ne pas être d'accord

**Dans le cas d'un temps composé, l'auxiliaire est le verbe conjugué** : il se place entre *ne* et *pas*. Le participe passé vient après *pas*.

> Je n'ai pas donné mon accord.
>   Je ne suis pas allé à cette soirée.

***Y* et *en* se placent entre *ne* et le verbe conjugué.**

> Je n'en ai pas voulu.
>   Je n'y suis pas allé.
>   Il n'y en a pas.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Je n'ai pas trouvé de référence rapide, cette règle est juste trop ancrée en moi et fait partie de celles auxquelles j'ai du mal à trouver des exceptions, alors qu'on dit que ce sont elles qui constituent notre langue.</sub>

Comment: Peut-être nuancer l'exemple avec le verbe à l'infinitif ; même si votre proposition est plus naturelle on peut aussi dire "***N**'être **pas** d'accord* avec ce raisonnement n'implique pas ***ne pas** être d'accord*  avec le résultat".

Comment: @cl-r dans ton exemple, je pense qu'on dirait plutôt "être pas d'accord", sans le "ne", qui serait "être « la négation de d'accord »" plutôt que "la négation de « être d'accord »"

Comment: Les deux sont audibles et équivalents, peut-être avec une nuance plus soutenue ou plus littéraire si l'on ajoute le *ne* avant le verbe, et un usage à l'oral sans ce dernier.

Comment: Je relis un courrier et je tombe sur un cas intéressant qui peut enrichir cette discussion : « Je regrette de n'avoir pas pu... » ou « Je regrette de ne pas avoir pu... » ? C'est un infinitif, mais c'est l'auxiliaire qui est à l'infinitif. Est-ce que cela a une incidence ? J'avoue que je sèche.

Answer (score 2):

Plutôt qu'une tournure négative, on peut aussi utiliser l'adjectif signifiant "qui n'est pas intéressant":

> Mon travail est inintéressant.

Answer (score 0):

> Mon travail est intéressant

Le verbe est conjugué mais à un temps simple,  donc  la négation **ne** ... **pas** encadre le verbe en question.

On obtient donc:

> Mon travail **n**'est **pas** intéressant